# generate a pdf with html2pdf in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have add html2pdf in wordpress for generate a pdf file.

My pdf are generate but the problem are in the code of pdf. When i  open the file in my editor i see the DOM of admin wordpress. and my file is not good for reading with adobe reader.

Firefox console display 100 lines "Warning: Ignoring invalid character "93" in hex string"

Ex of code :

```
ob_start();
$content = 'bonjour';
require_once 'inc/pdf/vendor/autoload.php';
$html2pdf = new Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf();
$html2pdf->writeHtml($content);
$html2pdf->output('test.pdf');
```

do you have an idea to run the code but not in the wordpress dom?

Comment: What's with this: `ob_start();`? This is usually followed by an `ob_get_contents()` or something similar. So right now you are buffering the whole $html2pdf creation process, is this what their documentation suggests?

Comment: I have read all exemple and i have tested all. I have tryed with ob_get_content but  i have th same probleme. the problem are html2pdf generate all code of admin wordpress not just my content.